# how to change the first day of the week in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I need to change the week start date from Monday to Saturday in *PostgreSQL*. I have tried `SET DATEFIRST 6;` but it doesn't work in *PostgreSQL*. Please suggest solution for this.

Comment: Where in [the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/index.html) did you find the statement `set datefirst`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It appears that `DATEFIRST` is a thing in *Microsoft Transact-SQL*.

I don't believe *Postgres* has any exact equivalent, but you should be able to approximate it.

*Postgres* supports extracting various parts of a `TIMESTAMP` via the `EXTRACT` function. For your purposes, you would want to use either `DOW` or `ISODOW`.

`DOW` numbers Sunday (0) through Saturday (6), while `ISODOW`, which adheres to the *ISO 8601* standard, numbers Monday (1) through Sunday (7).

From the [Postgres doc](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html):

This:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(DOW FROM TIMESTAMP '2001-02-18 20:38:40');
```

Returns `0`, while this:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(ISODOW FROM TIMESTAMP '2001-02-18 20:38:40');
```

Returns `7`.

So you would use a version of `EXTRACT` in your queries to get the day of the week number. If you're going to use it in many queries, I would recommend [creating a function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createfunction.html) which would centralize the query in one spot, and return the number transposed as you would like such that it started on Saturday (the transposition would vary depending on which numbering method you used in `EXTRACT`). Then you could simply call that function in any `SELECT` and it would return the transposed number.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add +x, where x is the offset between postgres dow and what you want to achieve.

For example:

You want Sunday to be the first day of the week. 2018-06-03 is a Sunday and you want to extract the dow of it:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(DOW FROM DATE '2018-06-03')+1;
```

returns `1`

That is probably the reason why postgres dow yields 0 for Sunday. Would it be 7, then

```
SELECT EXTRACT(DOW FROM DATE '2018-06-03')+1;
```

would return `8`.