# Postgres: How to change start day of week and apply it in date_part?

Tags: postgresql

```
with partial as(
    select 
    date_part('week', activated_at) as weekly, 
    count(*) as count
    from vendors
    where activated_at notnull 
    group by weekly
)
```

This is the query counts number of vendors activating per week. I need to change the start day of week from Monday to Saturday. Similar posts like [how to change the first day of the week in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26858406/how-to-change-the-first-day-of-the-week-in-postgresql) or [Making Postgres date_trunc() use a Sunday based week](https://blog.0101010.com/making-date-trunc-use-a-sunday-week/) but non explain how to embed it in `date_part` function. I would like to know how to use this function in my query and start day from Saturday.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you define how you want the week to be calculated? Don't forget to consider days near new year's day.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe the given links add `+2` to the default

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name it reports error `ERROR: syntax error at or near "select" Position: 310`

Comment: That was not really an answer to my question...

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe well, I really have no idea. It seems every thing should be shifted 2 days

Answer (score 1):

maybe a little bit overkill for that, you can use some ctes and window functions, so first generate your intervals, start with your first saturday, you want  e.g. 2018-01-06 00:00 and the last day you want 2018-12-31, then select your data, join it , sum it and as benefit you also get weeks with zero activations:

```
 with temp_days as (
    SELECT a as a ,
    a + '7 days'::interval as e
    FROM generate_series('2018-01-06 00:00'::timestamp,
                                  '2018-12-31 00:00', '7 day') as a
    ),
    temp_data as (
    select 
    1 as counter,
    vendors.activated_at
      from vendors
    where activated_at notnull 
    ),
    temp_order as
    (
    select *
    from temp_days
    left join temp_data on temp_data.activated_at between (temp_days.a) and (temp_days.e)
    
    )
    select 
    distinct on (temp_order.a)
    temp_order.a,
    temp_order.e,
    coalesce(sum(temp_order.counter) over (partition by temp_order.a),0) as result
    from temp_order
```